# How to catch value with tags?

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

> <!--dle_image_begin:http://some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/1.png|--><img
>   src="some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/1.png" alt="***" title="***"
>    /><!--dle_image_end--> bla bla bla bla
>   <!--dle_image_begin:http://some_url.com/image/2.png|--><img
>   src="some_url.com/uploads/image/2.png" alt="***" title="***"
>    /><!--dle_image_end--> bla bla bla
>   <!--dle_image_begin:http://some_url.com/asfafsdsaf|--><img
>   src="some_url.com/asfafsdsaf" alt="***" title="***"
>    /><!--dle_image_end-->

How to catch every `<!--dle_image_begin: ... <!--dle_image_end-->` with `prey_match_all`? It really doesn't matter what is between `dle_image_begin` and `dle_image_end` - i just need to have each of it in array (including `dle_image_begin` and `dle_image_end` tags).

I tried: something like `<!--dle_image_begin:.*([^|]dle_image_end-->)` and `<!--dle_image_begin:.*?(<--dle_image_end-->)`, but still can't understand how it works... Can someone give a tip on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this regex

```
/(<!--dle_image_begin.*?dle_image_end-->)/
```

with `preg_match_all( '/(<!--dle_image_begin.*?dle_image_end-->)/', $code, $matches )`.
`$matches` will contain all matches.

It will match patterns that start with `<!--dle_image_begin` and ends with `dle_image_end-->` with anything between it. The parenthesis around are neccesarry to match the whole expression, not only a part.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.  `<--dle_image_end` should be `<!--dle_image_end` and you can leave out the parens:

```
<?php

  $source = <<<SOURCE_HEREDOC
<!--dle_image_begin:http://some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/1.png|--><img src="some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/1.png" alt="" title=""  /><!--dle_image_end--> bla bla bla bla <!--dle_image_begin:http://some_url.com/image/2.png|--><img src="some_url.com/uploads/image/2.png" alt="" title=""  /><!--dle_image_end--> bla bla bla <!--dle_image_begin:http://some_url.com/asfafsdsaf|--><img src="some_url.com/asfafsdsaf" alt="" title=""  /><!--dle_image_end-->
SOURCE_HEREDOC;

  $regex = "/<!--dle_image_begin:.*?--dle_image_end-->/";

  preg_match_all($regex,trim($source),$matches);

  echo "\n";
  foreach($matches as $match) {
    foreach($match as $part) {
      echo "\n";
      echo "  -> ".$part;
      echo "\n";
    }
  }
  echo "\n";
?>
```

output:

```
  -> <!--dle_image_begin:http://some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/1.png|--><img src="some_url.com/uploads/posts/2012-12/1.png" alt="" title=""  /><!--dle_image_end-->

  -> <!--dle_image_begin:http://some_url.com/image/2.png|--><img src="some_url.com/uploads/image/2.png" alt="" title=""  /><!--dle_image_end-->

  -> <!--dle_image_begin:http://some_url.com/asfafsdsaf|--><img src="some_url.com/asfafsdsaf" alt="" title=""  /><!--dle_image_end-->
```